# How to interpolate a column within a grouped object in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, interpolation

How do you interpolate a PySpark dataframe within grouped data?

For example:

I have a PySpark dataframe with the following columns:

```
+--------+-------------------+--------+
|webID   |timestamp          |counts  |
+--------+-------------------+--------+
|John    |2018-02-01 03:00:00|60      |
|John    |2018-02-01 03:03:00|66      |
|John    |2018-02-01 03:05:00|70      |
|John    |2018-02-01 03:08:00|76      |
|Mo      |2017-06-04 01:05:00|10      |
|Mo      |2017-06-04 01:07:00|20      |
|Mo      |2017-06-04 01:10:00|35      |
|Mo      |2017-06-04 01:11:00|40      |
+--------+----------------- -+--------+
```

I need to interpolate both John and Mo's count data to a datapoint every minute, within their own interval. I am open to any simple linear interpolation - but note that my real data is every few seconds and I want to interpolate to every second.

So the result should be:

```
+--------+-------------------+--------+
|webID   |timestamp          |counts  |
+--------+-------------------+--------+
|John    |2018-02-01 03:00:00|60      |
|John    |2018-02-01 03:01:00|62      |
|John    |2018-02-01 03:02:00|64      |
|John    |2018-02-01 03:03:00|66      |
|John    |2018-02-01 03:04:00|68      |
|John    |2018-02-01 03:05:00|70      |
|John    |2018-02-01 03:06:00|72      |
|John    |2018-02-01 03:07:00|74      |
|John    |2018-02-01 03:08:00|76      |
|Mo      |2017-06-04 01:05:00|10      |
|Mo      |2017-06-04 01:06:00|15      |
|Mo      |2017-06-04 01:07:00|20      |
|Mo      |2017-06-04 01:08:00|25      |
|Mo      |2017-06-04 01:09:00|30      |
|Mo      |2017-06-04 01:10:00|35      |
|Mo      |2017-06-04 01:11:00|40      |
+--------+----------------- -+--------+
```

New rows need to be added to my original dataframe.
Looking for a PySpark solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Python the shortest way to get things done is to re-use existing Pandas functions, with `GROUPED_MAP` udf:

```py
from operator import attrgetter
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

def resample(schema, freq, timestamp_col = "timestamp",**kwargs):
    @pandas_udf(
        StructType(sorted(schema, key=attrgetter("name"))), 
        PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def _(pdf):
        pdf.set_index(timestamp_col, inplace=True)
        pdf = pdf.resample(freq).interpolate()
        pdf.ffill(inplace=True)
        pdf.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
        pdf.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
        return pdf
    return _
```

Applied on your data:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("John",   "2018-02-01 03:00:00", 60),  
    ("John",   "2018-02-01 03:03:00", 66),  
    ("John",   "2018-02-01 03:05:00", 70),  
    ("John",   "2018-02-01 03:08:00", 76),  
    ("Mo",     "2017-06-04 01:05:00", 10),  
    ("Mo",     "2017-06-04 01:07:00", 20),  
    ("Mo",     "2017-06-04 01:10:00", 35),  
    ("Mo",     "2017-06-04 01:11:00", 40),
], ("webID", "timestamp", "counts")).withColumn(
  "timestamp", to_timestamp("timestamp")
)

df.groupBy("webID").apply(resample(df.schema, "60S")).show()
```

it yields

```
+------+-------------------+-----+
|counts|          timestamp|webID|
+------+-------------------+-----+
|    60|2018-02-01 03:00:00| John|
|    62|2018-02-01 03:01:00| John|
|    64|2018-02-01 03:02:00| John|
|    66|2018-02-01 03:03:00| John|
|    68|2018-02-01 03:04:00| John|
|    70|2018-02-01 03:05:00| John|
|    72|2018-02-01 03:06:00| John|
|    74|2018-02-01 03:07:00| John|
|    76|2018-02-01 03:08:00| John|
|    10|2017-06-04 01:05:00|   Mo|
|    15|2017-06-04 01:06:00|   Mo|
|    20|2017-06-04 01:07:00|   Mo|
|    25|2017-06-04 01:08:00|   Mo|
|    30|2017-06-04 01:09:00|   Mo|
|    35|2017-06-04 01:10:00|   Mo|
|    40|2017-06-04 01:11:00|   Mo|
+------+-------------------+-----+
```

This works under the assumption that both input and interpolated data for a single `webID` can fit in a memory of a single node (in general other exact, non-iterative solutions will have to make similar assumptions). If that's not the case you can easily approximate by taking overlapping windows

```py
partial = (df
    .groupBy("webID", window("timestamp", "5 minutes", "3 minutes")["start"])
    .apply(resample(df.schema, "60S")))
```

and aggregating the final result

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean

(partial
    .groupBy("webID", "timestamp")
    .agg(mean("counts")
    .alias("counts"))
    # Order by key and timestamp, only for consistent presentation
    .orderBy("webId", "timestamp")
    .show())
```

This of course is much more expensive (there are two shuffles, and some values will be computed multiple times), but also can leave gaps, if overlap is not large enough to include the next observation.

```
+-----+-------------------+------+
|webID|          timestamp|counts|
+-----+-------------------+------+
| John|2018-02-01 03:00:00|  60.0|
| John|2018-02-01 03:01:00|  62.0|
| John|2018-02-01 03:02:00|  64.0|
| John|2018-02-01 03:03:00|  66.0|
| John|2018-02-01 03:04:00|  68.0|
| John|2018-02-01 03:05:00|  70.0|
| John|2018-02-01 03:08:00|  76.0|
|   Mo|2017-06-04 01:05:00|  10.0|
|   Mo|2017-06-04 01:06:00|  15.0|
|   Mo|2017-06-04 01:07:00|  20.0|
|   Mo|2017-06-04 01:08:00|  25.0|
|   Mo|2017-06-04 01:09:00|  30.0|
|   Mo|2017-06-04 01:10:00|  35.0|
|   Mo|2017-06-04 01:11:00|  40.0|
+-----+-------------------+------+
```

Comment: Just a FYI - the unit for seconds is capital "S". Otherwise this works. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works for 60S, but i get errors for 1S. Do you know why?

Answer (score 5):

A native pyspark implementation (no udf's) that tackles this problem is:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
resample_interval = 1  # Resample interval size in seconds

df_interpolated = (
  df_data
  # Get timestamp and Counts of previous measurement via window function
  .selectExpr(
    "webID",
    "LAG(Timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY webID ORDER BY Timestamp ASC) as PreviousTimestamp",
    "Timestamp as NextTimestamp",
    "LAG(Counts) OVER (PARTITION BY webID ORDER BY Timestamp ASC) as PreviousCounts",
    "Counts as NextCounts",
  )
  # To determine resample interval round up start and round down end timeinterval to nearest interval boundary
  .withColumn("PreviousTimestampRoundUp", F.expr(f"to_timestamp(ceil(unix_timestamp(PreviousTimestamp)/{resample_interval})*{resample_interval})"))
  .withColumn("NextTimestampRoundDown", F.expr(f"to_timestamp(floor(unix_timestamp(NextTimestamp)/{resample_interval})*{resample_interval})"))
  # Make sure we don't get any negative intervals (whole interval is within resample interval)
  .filter("PreviousTimestampRoundUp<=NextTimestampRoundDown")
  # Create resampled time axis by creating all "interval" timestamps between previous and next timestamp
  .withColumn("Timestamp", F.expr(f"explode(sequence(PreviousTimestampRoundUp, NextTimestampRoundDown, interval {resample_interval} second)) as Timestamp"))
  # Sequence has inclusive boundaries for both start and stop. Filter out duplicate Counts if original timestamp is exactly a boundary.
  .filter("Timestamp<NextTimestamp")
  # Interpolate Counts between previous and next
  .selectExpr(
    "webID",
    "Timestamp", 
    """(unix_timestamp(Timestamp)-unix_timestamp(PreviousTimestamp))
        /(unix_timestamp(NextTimestamp)-unix_timestamp(PreviousTimestamp))
        *(NextCounts-PreviousCounts) 
        +PreviousCounts
        as Counts"""
  )
)
```

I recently have written a blogpost explaining this method and showing that this method scales much better for big datasets compared to the pandas udf method above : https://medium.com/delaware-pro/interpolate-big-data-time-series-in-native-pyspark-d270d4b592a1

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a `Python` solution, but I suppose the `Scala` solution below could be implemented using a similar approach in `Python`.  It involves using the `lag` Window function to create a time range in each row and a UDF that expands the time range via the `java.time` API into a list of `per-minute` time series and interpolated counts, which is then flattened with Spark's `explode` method:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("John", "2018-02-01 03:00:00", 60),
  ("John", "2018-02-01 03:03:00", 66),
  ("John", "2018-02-01 03:05:00", 70),
  ("Mo", "2017-06-04 01:07:00", 20),
  ("Mo", "2017-06-04 01:10:00", 35),
  ("Mo", "2017-06-04 01:11:00", 40)
).toDF("webID", "timestamp", "count")

val winSpec = Window.partitionBy($"webID").orderBy($"timestamp")

def minuteList(timePattern: String) = udf{ (ts1: String, ts2: String, c1: Int, c2: Int) =>
  import java.time.LocalDateTime
  import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

  val timeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timePattern)

  val perMinTS = if (ts1 == ts2) Vector(ts1) else {
      val t1 = LocalDateTime.parse(ts1, timeFormat)
      val t2 = LocalDateTime.parse(ts2, timeFormat)
      Iterator.iterate(t1.plusMinutes(1))(_.plusMinutes(1)).takeWhile(! _.isAfter(t2)).
        map(_.format(timeFormat)).
        toVector
    }

  val sz = perMinTS.size

  val perMinCount = for { i <- 1 to sz } yield c1 + ((c2 - c1) * i / sz)

  perMinTS zip perMinCount
}

df.
  withColumn("timestampPrev", when(row_number.over(winSpec) === 1, $"timestamp").
    otherwise(lag($"timestamp", 1).over(winSpec))).
  withColumn("countPrev", when(row_number.over(winSpec) === 1, $"count").
    otherwise(lag($"count", 1).over(winSpec))).
  withColumn("minuteList",
    minuteList("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")($"timestampPrev", $"timestamp", $"countPrev", $"count")).
  withColumn("minute", explode($"minuteList")).
  select($"webID", $"minute._1".as("timestamp"), $"minute._2".as("count")).
  show
// +-----+-------------------+-----+
// |webID|          timestamp|count|
// +-----+-------------------+-----+
// | John|2018-02-01 03:00:00|   60|
// | John|2018-02-01 03:01:00|   62|
// | John|2018-02-01 03:02:00|   64|
// | John|2018-02-01 03:03:00|   66|
// | John|2018-02-01 03:04:00|   68|
// | John|2018-02-01 03:05:00|   70|
// |   Mo|2017-06-04 01:07:00|   20|
// |   Mo|2017-06-04 01:08:00|   25|
// |   Mo|2017-06-04 01:09:00|   30|
// |   Mo|2017-06-04 01:10:00|   35|
// |   Mo|2017-06-04 01:11:00|   40|
// +-----+-------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

I extended the great answer from [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66829584/11399142) and made it dynamic to use it on wider dataframes and make it reusable.

It takes the group and time column names as input variables:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

resample_interval = 1  # Resample interval size in seconds
group_str = 'webID'    # name of group column
time_str = 'timestamp' # name of timestamp column
```

Then dynamically detect what other columns are present in the dataframe, then dynamically create the select expression and the interpolation expression proposed by David:

```
# extract columns to interpolate
interpol_col_str = df_data.drop(group_str, time_str).columns

# create select expression to get interpolation columns and previous measurement via window function
col_create_expr = []
for col in interpol_col_str:
  col_create_expr.extend([
  f"LAG({col}) OVER (PARTITION BY {group_str} ORDER BY {time_str} ASC) as Previous{col}",
  f"{col} as Next{col}"
  ])

# create interpolation expression for each interpolation column
interpol_expr = []
for col in interpol_col_str:
  interpol_expr.extend([
      f"""(unix_timestamp({time_str})-unix_timestamp(Previous{time_str}))
        /(unix_timestamp(Next{time_str})-unix_timestamp(Previous{time_str}))
        *(Next{col}-Previous{col}) 
        +Previous{col}
        as {col}"""]
  )
```

The expressions can be added to the interpolation method by unpacking the lists with the `*` -> `*col_create_expr` and `*interpol_expr`:

```
df_interpolated = (
  df_data
  # Get timestamp and interpolation columns of previous measurement via window function
  .selectExpr(
    f"{group_str}",
    f"LAG({time_str}) OVER (PARTITION BY {group_str} ORDER BY {time_str} ASC) as Previous{time_str}",
    f"{time_str} as Next{time_str}",
    *col_create_expr
  )
  # To determine resample interval round up start and round down end timeinterval to nearest interval boundary
  .withColumn(f"Previous{time_str}RoundUp", f.expr(f"to_timestamp(ceil(unix_timestamp(Previous{time_str})/{resample_interval})*{resample_interval})"))
  .withColumn(f"Next{time_str}RoundDown", f.expr(f"to_timestamp(floor(unix_timestamp(Next{time_str})/{resample_interval})*{resample_interval})"))
  # Make sure we don't get any negative intervals (whole interval is within resample interval)
  .filter(f"Previous{time_str}RoundUp<=Next{time_str}RoundDown")
  # Create resampled time axis by creating all "interval" timestamps between previous and next timestamp
  .withColumn(f"{time_str}", f.expr(f"explode(sequence(Previous{time_str}RoundUp, Next{time_str}RoundDown, interval {resample_interval} second)) as {time_str}"))
  # Sequence has inclusive boundaries for both start and stop. Filter out duplicate {column_str} if original timestamp is exactly a boundary.
  .filter(f"{time_str}<Next{time_str}")
  # Interpolate {column_str} between previous and next
  .selectExpr(
    f"{group_str}",
    f"{time_str}", 
    *interpol_expr
  )
)
```